# MVC 5 Identity 2.0 Allow Login using Email or Recovery Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

The requirement for the website is the ability to login using the email address or a recovery email address in a single text box.  I have extended the user.identity property to include a recover email.  I have also added an update to the AccountController to check the email address entered against the email and the RecoveryEmail field.  However, I need to modify the email validation upon registration because it cannot exist in the recovery email field either.  From another post, I have created a CustomUserValidation but I cannot access the new identity field.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("RecoveryEmail", this.RecoveryEmail.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }
    public string RecoveryEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created an extension

```
namespace TestSecurity.Extensions
{
    public static class IdentityExtensions
    {
        public static string GetRecoveryEmail(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("RecoveryEmail");
            return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a CustomUserValidator class that requires when registering an email, it has to be unique within Email field but also within RecoveryEmail.

```
public class CustomUserValidator<TUser> : IIdentityValidator<TUser>
    where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
{
    private readonly UserManager<TUser> _manager;
    public CustomUserValidator()
    {
    }

    public CustomUserValidator(UserManager<TUser> manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(TUser item)
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();

        if (_manager != null)
        {
            //check if email exists in recovery email


            var findEmail= await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(item.UserName);
            var findRecoveryEmail = ???

        }
        return errors.Any()
            ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray())
        : IdentityResult.Success;

    }

    Task<IdentityResult> IIdentityValidator<TUser>.ValidateAsync(TUser item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am not certain what to add in the ???.  I have added the reference using TestSecurity.Extensions, but I cannot access this RecoveryEmail field to search.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about `public class CustomUserValidator<TUser> : IIdentityValidator<TUser> where TUser : ApplicationUser`

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.

Comment: throwing notImplementedException error.  using the following to call `var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));  um.UserValidator = new CustomUserValidator<ApplicationUser>(um);  var result1 = um.CreateAsync(user);`   It does not seem to reach the `public async Task<IdentityResult>'.  Head scratching.